# How to make each directive inside ng-repeat to share the same ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/422/)

JS file

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.foo = "I'm foo!";
    $scope.test = [1,2,3,5,6,7];

    $scope.$watch('foo', function(){
     console.log($scope.foo);
    });
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" /></div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel : '=',
        },
        link: function(scope){
          scope.ngModel = 'test';
        }
    };
});
```

HTML file

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{foo}}<br />
   <div ng-repeat="k in test">
       <my-directive ng-model="foo" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to make each `my-directive` to share the same `ng-model` `foo` , we can observe that if we take out the ng-repeat and only have one directive it works, however if we have multiple directives it doesn't work.

For example

having multiple directives like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/423/)

```
    <my-directive ng-model="foo" />
    <my-directive class="2" ng-model="foo" />
```

will only create one input

having multiple directive using ng-repeat will completely break the directive

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{foo}}<br />
   <div ng-repeat="k in test">
       <my-directive ng-model="foo" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't quite understand why is this happening, can someone give me some insight?

Comment: Check out http://jsfiddle.net/XyUGE/424/ I've removed the child scope on the directive and attached the model to the controller (models with a `.` are important)

Comment: Does this mean that the directive now share scope with the controller? What is the implication of getting rid of the isolated scope?

Comment: (Sorry, went to bed..) Yes, the directives are now checking the controller's scope - the negative impact of this would be if each directive wanted to have a scope variable of the same name with a different value per instance.

Answer (score 0):

So you are attempting to use each value in the array `test` as an option and, when one of them is clicked, the value of `foo` (your ngModel) should be updated to the value of that option. Is that correct?

If so, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/btshp2a3/

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      options: '='
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="option in options"><button ng-click="select(option)">{{ option }}</button></li></ul>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelController) {
      scope.select = function(option) {
        ngModelController.$setViewValue(option);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

**Usage**

```
<my-directive ng-model="foo" options="test"></my-directive>
```

Notice that the directive requires `ngModel` on the element. It then creates a list of clickable options based on the `options` variable, which should be an array. When an option is clicked, the directive informs the `ngModel` controller of the change.

[Here is a great article](http://radify.io/blog/understanding-ngmodelcontroller-by-example-part-1/) that explains how you can work with [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) in your custom directive to do even more interesting things.